# Caching in an Expression engine addon

Tags: php, performance, codeigniter, caching, expressionengine

I'm building an add-on for `ExpressionEngine 2.x` and I'd like to cache some data on the server. Specifically, I'd like to cache the result of parsing a template so I don't have to parse it again for the same request.

At the moment I'm using `$_SESSION`, but that only caches for that user. Ideally, I'd like to store the cache for everyone in memory or on disk.  I've also tried `$this->EE->session->cache`, but that only caches for the current request.  I've had a look at the caching driver for CodeIgnitor, but I'm not sure how I can get it working from within my add-on in ExpressionEngine: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/caching.html

I could also go with using `Memcache` or writing to a file, but as it needs to work on lots of different setups, there's no guarantee Memcache will be installed or there will be any writable folders.

Any ideas?

Comment: CE Cache (http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-cache) uses config settings to allow the developer to choose what caching settings they use dependant on what is installed on the server - maybe consider that sort of approach...? So build it for Memcache and if it's not detected or chosen, fall back to file or database or no caching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once rewrote parts of the CI-caching mechanism. Maybe this can be of any help to you. It is a 'cache' everything function. I wrote it as an override to the system-file.

There is an example of usage in it. It should be very simple. With this code you can cache any functions result, even share between sessions / requests.

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/221313/

Or this one:

https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/1646

If you don't need this new functionality, you can use it as an example on how to use the standard CI caching mechanism.

Like this:

```
class your_class extends CI_Model
{
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    function __construct( )
    {
        $cache_adapter = 'apc';
        $this->load->driver( 'cache', array( 'adapter' => $cache_adapter, 'backup' => 'dummy' ) );
        $this->cache->{$cache_adapter}->is_supported( );
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public function your_function( $arg )
    {
        $result = $this->cache->get( __CLASS__ . __METHOD__ . serialize( $arg ) );

        if ( empty( $result ) )
        {
            $result = ... /* your calculation here */

            $this->cache->save( __CLASS__ . __METHOD__  . serialize( $arg ) );
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

The key I use for the cache is the so called mangled function name. If the result of your function depends solely on its argumens (as it should), you can use it as is. For compactness of the key you could hash it. Like this:

```
    public function your_function( $arg )
    {
        $result = $this->cache->get( md5( __CLASS__ . __METHOD__ . serialize( $arg ) ) );

        if ( empty( $result ) )
        {
            $result = ... /* your calculation here */

            $this->cache->save( md5( __CLASS__ . __METHOD__  . serialize( $arg ) ) );
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that's some useful code. However I can't modify anything outside of the third_party folder if I'm going to distribute it as an addon.

Comment: Agreed. Just use the standard EE caching. See my code for an example on how to use.

Comment: Cheers. I think I'll go with using PHP's apc caching for now as that seems to be commonly enabled. Unfortunately I can't find a way to call CodeIgnitor's $this->load->driver function from EE, however that code has pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: I editted my solution to include a generic example on how to use the CI caching. Now please give me your vote ;)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest method: instruct your add-on's users to use EE's native tag caching to improve performance. Tag caching works per-EE tag, regardless of user.

Alternately, you can create a database table on install to hold your cached data and use that. Depending of how much and what kind of data you're caching, it could or could not yield performance gains.

Comment: Native tag caching is a good solution, but only if it's a module or plug-in, not fieldtype or extension.

Comment: That would be great but I'd like to choose when to use the cache as the content will change based on the url, and I'd like to do some things even if it does use the cache. Caching in the database is a good idea though, I might look into that.